# Springer Nature LaTeX Template and Tikz Issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates

The springer latex template is not working with Tikz.
Link: https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support
Output error:

```
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}

\jyear{2021}%

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}


\abstract{abc}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19):

As Simon posted a second before me:-) This can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{program}
%\catcode`\|=12\relax

\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

The `program` package makes `|` active already in the preamble which is rather optimistic, uncommenting the catcode setting restores the standard behaviour.
this is probably preferable than using a local copy of the class that will not work for submission.

Comment: \RequirePackage{tikz} solves the problem. So this is another example where \RequirePackage{} is actually useful.

Comment: @AMani no. `\RequirePackage` is identical to `\usepacklage`  they do not have two definitions one is literally a copy of the other using `\let` , usepackage is defined by `\let\usepackage\RequirePackage` oh, before the class, OK. (but it only works for this example, if you actually use `|` anywhere it will be broken by the `program` package,.

Comment: The `program` package is an absolute nightmare. Besides the active `|` which breaks its normal usage as a math delimiter, it redefines the standard `\S` and `\P` commands and hijacks many one-letter and other short macro names (`\A`, `\B`, `\Q`, ..., `\d`, `\e`, `\p`, ...), leading to a never-ending list of conflicts with user macros. The (recent, as far as I can tell) decision to forcefully include it in the Springer Nature classes is totally insane, as well as useless (they also redundantly include 4 other similar packages: `algorithm`, `algorithmicx`, `algpseudocode`, and `listings`).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yes, you could try reporting it but I would not have much hope of change

Answer (score 18):

`\RequirePackage{tikz}` before `\documentclass{...}` works

Comment: My saviour! Thanks.

Comment: @AMani, Hello ma'am.. It's been a long time. Hopefully, you'd see this! Actually I am facing the same issue at the moment. I tried your approach, but it's not working. Would you tell me what exactly did you do back then? Did you edit the class file as suggested by @Simon?

Comment: No I did not edit the class file.  My preamble:                                                                \RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\documentclass[referee,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{amsmath}  etc

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a conflict with the package `program`. Commenting the line #311 of the file `sn-jnl.cls` makes the problem go away.

And later adding    `\usepackage{program}` **after** tikz  works fine.

```
\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl} %  using .cls edited

\jyear{2021}%


%\usepackage{program}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<this fails
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{program}% <<<<<<<<<<<<< works OK

\begin{document}
    
    \title[Article Title]{Article Title}
    
    \author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    
    \abstract{abc}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec1}  
    
\end{document}
```

[image: A]

Comment: it only works to load program after you have edited the class not to load it (and you can't use an edited class for submission to Springer (you could try complaining to springer and getting them to not include the progtam package though)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to add the command `\normalbaroutside` after the `program` or one of the `sn-*` packages is loaded. Like this

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} % or \usepackage{program}
\normalbaroutside

\usepackage{tikz-cd} % or \usepackage{tikz}
```

This command neutralizes the conflicting behavior of `|` outside the `{program}` environment. It is documented within `program.sty`, but nowhere else it seems:

```
% program.sty, Version 3.3.14
% Version History:
  ...
% 3.3.4: Added \ifVBarOutsideProgram switch -- The command \normalbaroutside
%        makes | to act normally outside the program environment
  ...
% Set switch to false if you want | to act normally 
% outside the program environment:
\newif\ifVBarOutsideProgram \VBarOutsideProgramtrue
\def\normalbaroutside{\catcode`\|=12 \VBarOutsideProgramfalse}
  ...
```

Comment: Same solution as this [earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619283) by David Carlisle.