# Error compiling with tcolorbox and tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tcolorbox, compilation-error

I'm using the official [springer nature template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq). But whenever I try to add `tcolorbox` or `tikz` package it throws the following error. I've removed the content of the template but it's still there.

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.888 ...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}
                                                  
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 15
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 888.

<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.15 \input pgfmathparser.code.tex
                                  
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

 Learn more
<argument> \csname\endcsname\let \filename@area 
                                                \@empty \expandafter \filena...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

 Learn more
<argument> \csname\endcsname\def \filename@ext 
                                               {tex}\edef \filename@base {pg...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ename@ext {tex}\edef \filename@base 
                                                  {pgfcore.code}\else \filen...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \csname\endcsname\let \filename@area 
                                                \@empty \expandafter \filena...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \csname\endcsname\def \filename@ext 
                                               {tex}\edef \filename@base {pg...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

 Learn more
<argument> ...ename@ext {tex}\edef \filename@base 
                                                  {pgfcore.code}\else \filen...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex, line 16
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \csname\endcsname\let \filename@area 
                                                \@empty \expandafter \filena...
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11316 strings out of 480906
 174053 string characters out of 5908280
 453888 words of memory out of 5000000
 26664 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 541069 words of font info for 53 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1151 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 202i,5n,245p,326b,216s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Probably related: [Springer Nature LaTeX Template and Tikz Issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615012/134144)