# Springer Nature 2021 incompatible with all (but here with tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, springernature

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
This causes an error
\end{document}
```

How can I include TikZ code?  (I cannot just include the pictures generated by TikZ, so I'd just end up publishing elsewhere). A short list of the huge number of errors I get is:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.888 ...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}
                                                  
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 888.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.15 \input pgfmathparser.code.tex
                                  
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let  
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 888.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.15 \input pgfmathparser.code.tex
                                  
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.16 \input
            pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>  
......
l.233 \pgfmath@tokens@make{box}{\wd\ht\dp}
                                          
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.233 \pgfmath@tokens@make{box}{\wd\ht\dp}
                                          
! Use of \pgfmath doesn't match its definition.
l.235   \pgfmath@tokens@m
                         ake{dimexpr}{\dimexpr\glueexpr}
! You can't use `\dimexpr' in horizontal mode.
l.235   \pgfmath@tokens@make{dimexpr}{\dimexpr
                                              \glueexpr}
! You can't use `\glueexpr' in horizontal mode.
l.235 ...th@tokens@make{dimexpr}{\dimexpr\glueexpr
                                                  }
! Use of \pgfmath doesn't match its definition.
l.237 \pgfmath@tokens@m
                       ake{unit}{{bp}{cc}{cm}{dd}{em}{ex}{in}{mm}{pc}{pt}{sp}}
! Use of \pgfmath doesn't match its definition.
l.238 \pgfmath@tokens@m
                       ake{mathunit}{{mu}}
! Use of \pgfmath doesn't match its definition.
l.239 \pgfmath@tokens@m
                       ake{numeric}{.0123456789}
! Use of \pgfmath doesn't match its definition.
l.240 \pgfmath@tokens@m
                       ake{number}{0123456789}
! Use of \pgfmath doesn't match its definition.
l.241 \pgfmath@tokens@m
                       ake{functional}{_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJ...

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. This is the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615012/springer-nature-latex-template-and-tikz-issue I think?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, thank you. That solved it.