# forest Package Tree Change with RequirePackage

Tags: forest, springernature

I am using the `forest` package to draw a simple tree.  When using `forest` with the Springer-Nature template, `forest` must be specified via a `\RequirePackage` callout before calling `\documentclass`.  This unfortunately changes the tree structure.  I provide an MWE (at the end) where the issue is replicated with the `article` `documentclass` for simplicity.

**Expected Output:**

Observe that the fork points are separated from the parent node

[image: Expected Output]

**Alternate Output**

When the command `\RequirePackage[edges]{forest}` is uncommented in the MWE, I get an alternate tree where the fork point is connected to the parent (see below).

[image: Collapsed Fork Point Format]

**Question**: How can I fix the `\RequirePackage` of `forest` so the second image appears like the first?  Recall I can't delete the `\RequirePackage` since the Springer-Nature `documentclass` requires it.

**Base MWE with `article` for Simplicity**

```
% \RequirePackage[edges]{forest}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}


\begin{document}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        draw=black!75,
        line width=1pt,
        if level=0{%
          forked edges,
          l sep+=0.35cm,
          s sep+=0.5in,
          align=center,
        }{%
          if level=1{%
            l sep+=0.35cm,
            s sep+=0.5in,
          }{
          },
        },%
      },
      [Node~A
        [Node~B
        ]
        [Node~C
           [Node~D
           ]
           [Node~E
           ]
        ]
     ]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `sn-jnl` class loads the package `program` that conflicts with `forest` or `edges`.  From CTAN:

> its main offering is a program environment; a programbox environment
> is available for snippets that should not break pages.

If you don't need such a programbox environment, you can avoid loading the `program` package.

Using

```
\makeatletter%
\disable@package@load{program}{}
\makeatother
```

prevents the `program` package from being loaded.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\makeatletter% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\disable@package@load{program}{}
\makeatother

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage[edges]{forest} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<,

\begin{document}        
        \scriptsize
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={
                draw=black!75,
                line width=1pt,
                if level=0{%
                    forked edges,
                    l sep+=0.35cm,
                    s sep+=0.5in,
                }{%
                    if level=1{%
                        l sep+=0.35cm,
                        s sep+=0.5in,
                    }{
                    },
                },%
            },
            [Node~A
            [Node~B
            ]
            [Node~C
            [Node~D
            ]
            [Node~E
            ]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Another option is to use [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615024/161015)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\catcode`\|=12\relax % added <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[edges]{forest} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<,

\begin{document}        
        \scriptsize
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={
                draw=black!75,
                line width=1pt,
                if level=0{%
                    forked edges,
                    l sep+=0.35cm,
                    s sep+=0.5in,
                }{%
                    if level=1{%
                        l sep+=0.35cm,
                        s sep+=0.5in,
                    }{
                    },
                },%
            },
            [Node~A
            [Node~B
            ]
            [Node~C
            [Node~D
            ]
            [Node~E
            ]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, don't ask me why.

```
\RequirePackage{forest}
\documentclass{article}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
```