# How can I add the ORCID ID with the .png file next to it?

Tags: png, springernature

I want to add the orcid link with the .png file. I'm using \documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}. I have tried several methods but none worked. I would like it to look something like this: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10801-022-01156-9.pdf .Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orcidlink` package does the job with the command `\orcidlink{<ORCiD digits>}`. It will add the symbol with the hyperlink.

However, for use with the `sn-jnl` class, loading the `program` package, the source of many conflicts, should be avoided.

This is done with the line `\disable@package@load{program}{}` before the class load.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\makeatletter% do not load the package program <<< added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\disable@package@load{program}{}
\makeatother

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{orcidlink} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \title[Article Title]{Article Title}
    
    \author[1]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0001}} \email{iauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \author[2]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0002}} \email{iiauthor@gmail.com}

    \affil[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}
    
    \keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}
    
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

    Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted. 
\end{document}
```

Another option is to use [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615024/161015)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex


\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\catcode`\|=12\relax % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{orcidlink} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}
    
    \title[Article Title]{Article Title}
    
    \author[1]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0001}} \email{iauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \author[2]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0002}} \email{iiauthor@gmail.com}

    \affil[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}
    
    \keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}
    
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

    Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second option helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @simon The logo is added after name but usually it should be added after the superscript i.e. {full name}{superscripts}{logo}. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, replacing xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx with your orcid number, of course:

```
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifTUTeX
  \RequirePackage{academicons}
  \definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
  \newcommand{\myorcid}{%
    \href{https://orcid.org/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}{\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\aiOrcid}} % 
  }
\else
  \RequirePackage{orcidlink}
  \newcommand{\myorcid}{\orcidlink{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}}
\fi
```