# How can I add the ORCID iD icon after the author and superscript?

Tags: springernature

I want to include the ORCID link with the .png file. I am using \documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} ([MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd)). I found an existing [Stack Overflow answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666449/how-can-i-add-the-orcid-id-with-the-png-file-next-to-it) that explains how to add an ORCID iD. I followed the instructions, and it was successful. However, the ID appears just after the name, as shown below in the image. I would like it to appear after the full name and superscripts, similar to this PDF: [Example PDF](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10801-022-01156-9.pdf).

I have attempted to place it in different positions; however, it always results in an error. Currently, I am doing it like this according to stackoverflow answer:

```
\author[1]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0001}} \email{iauthor@gmail.com}
```

The above code generates following output.
[image]